# Copy files from one set of folders to another

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to copy files in folders with a users name to a numbered set of folders. I'll illustrate:

```
adams
andrewp
claireb
johnd
mikej
```

Inside those folders might be any files; I want to copy them to folders called;

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5
```

and so on. Here is what i have so far, I want to figure out a way to parse the destination file in so the destination folders are from the destinationlist.txt.

```
$Sourcelist = gc "C:\Andy\PST\Source\sourcelist.txt"
$sourcepath = "C:\Andy\PST\Source"
$Destinationpath = "C:\Andy\PST\Destination"
$Destinationlist = gc "C:\Andy\PST\Destination\destlist.txt"
$Sourcelist | %{
ROBOCOPY "$sourcepath\$_" "C:\Andy\PST\Destination\$_." /MIR
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
   $Sourcelist = gc "C:\temp\sourcelist.txt"
   $sourcepath = "C:\temp\PST\Source"
   $Destinationpath = "C:\temp\PST\Destination"
   $Destinationlist = gc "C:\temp\destination.txt"

   for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Sourcelist.Count; $i++)
   { 
       copy-item "$sourcepath\$($Sourcelist[$i])" -Destination "$Destinationpath\$($Destinationlist[$i])\$($Sourcelist[$i])" -Force 
   }
```

Comment: Hi, that is really close, but the behaviour is that it copies the source folder into the destination folder without any files. I only need to copy the files from the source to the destination.